# Eloquent JavaScript, Sequence Interface

Tags: javascript

I am working my way through Eloquent JavaScript, and I am having questions about problem #6.3 (second edition).

Here is the problem:

> Design an interface that abstracts iteration over a collection of
>   values. An object that provides this interface represents a sequence,
>   and the interface must somehow make it possible for code that uses
>   such an object to iterate over the sequence, looking at the element
>   values it is made up of and having some way to find out when the end
>   of the sequence is reached.
>
> When you have specified your interface, try to write a function
>   logFive that takes a sequence object and calls console.log on its
>   first five elements—or fewer, if the sequence has fewer than five
>   elements.
>
> Then implement an object type ArraySeq that wraps an array and allows
>   iteration over the array using the interface you designed. Implement
>   another object type RangeSeq that iterates over a range of integers
>   (taking from and to arguments to its constructor) instead.

I wrote this solution:

```
function ArraySeq(collection) {
  this.values = collection;
}

ArraySeq.prototype.iterate = function(start, end, action) {
  var n = Math.min(this.values.length, end);
  for (var i = start; i < n; i++) {
    action(this.values[i]);
  }
};

function RangeSeq(from, to) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = from; i <= to; i++)
    array.push(i);
  ArraySeq.call(this, array);
}

RangeSeq.prototype = Object.create(ArraySeq.prototype);

function logFive(sequenceObject) {
 sequenceObject.iterate(0, 5, console.log);
}

//This code to test how the solution works was provided by the author
logFive(new ArraySeq([1, 2]));
// → 1
// → 2
logFive(new RangeSeq(100, 1000));
// → 100
// → 101
// → 102
// → 103
// → 104
```

The solutions by the author are different, here are both of them:

```
// I am going to use a system where a sequence object has two methods:
//
// * next(), which returns a boolean indicating whether there are more
//   elements in the sequence, and moves it forward to the next
//   element when there are.
//
// * current(), which returns the current element, and should only be
//   called after next() has returned true at least once.

function logFive(sequence) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (!sequence.next())
      break;
    console.log(sequence.current());
  }
}

function ArraySeq(array) {
  this.pos = -1;
  this.array = array;
}
ArraySeq.prototype.next = function() {
  if (this.pos >= this.array.length-1)
    return false;
  this.pos++;
  return true;
};
ArraySeq.prototype.current = function() {
  return this.array[this.pos];
};

function RangeSeq(from, to) {
  this.pos = from - 1;
  this.to = to;
}
RangeSeq.prototype.next = function() {
  if (this.pos >= this.to)
    return false;
  this.pos++;
  return true;
};
RangeSeq.prototype.current = function() {
  return this.pos;
};

logFive(new ArraySeq([1, 2]));
// → 1
// → 2
logFive(new RangeSeq(100, 1000));
// → 100
// → 101
// → 102
// → 103
// → 104

// This alternative approach represents the empty sequence as null,
// and gives non-empty sequences two methods:
//
// * head() returns the element at the start of the sequence.
// 
// * rest() returns the rest of the sequence, or null if there are no
//   elemements left.
//
// Because a JavaScript constructor can not return null, we add a make
// function to constructors of this type of sequence, which constructs
// a sequence, or returns null if the resulting sequence would be
// empty.

function logFive2(sequence) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5 && sequence != null; i++) {
    console.log(sequence.head());
    sequence = sequence.rest();
  }
}

function ArraySeq2(array, offset) {
  this.array = array;
  this.offset = offset;
}
ArraySeq2.prototype.rest = function() {
  return ArraySeq2.make(this.array, this.offset + 1);
};
ArraySeq2.prototype.head = function() {
  return this.array[this.offset];
};
ArraySeq2.make = function(array, offset) {
  if (offset == null) offset = 0;
  if (offset >= array.length)
    return null;
  else
    return new ArraySeq2(array, offset);
};

function RangeSeq2(from, to) {
  this.from = from;
  this.to = to;
}
RangeSeq2.prototype.rest = function() {
  return RangeSeq2.make(this.from + 1, this.to);
};
RangeSeq2.prototype.head = function() {
  return this.from;
};
RangeSeq2.make = function(from, to) {
  if (from > to)
    return null;
  else
    return new RangeSeq2(from, to);
};

logFive2(ArraySeq2.make([1, 2]));
// → 1
// → 2
logFive2(RangeSeq2.make(100, 1000));
// → 100
// → 101
// → 102
// → 103
// → 104
```

My questions:

1. My solution produces exactly the same results as the author's solutions. I tested all three with various test cases. I did utilize the material of the chapter when writing my solution (the chapter talks about OOP techniques in JavaScript, inheritance and such). **Given all this, is my solution wrong or not?**
2. Why are his solutions written the way they are written? I mean, is there something wrong with my approach? Not abstract enough? Is it a bad thing that my method accepts arguments? His methods do not require arguments. **Are there any drawbacks to my solution comparing to his?** (I must confess, I barely understood the problem, so my solution probably reflects the level of my understanding of the problem.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not correct, because the whole point of the iterator protocol is to iterate lazily, so that `RangeSeq(1, 10000000)` doesn't fill up memory with all elements if we only need five.

The author's code is ok, but unnecessarily verbose. Iterator protocols are usually implemented like this:

- an *Iterable* is an object that has the `iterator()` method
- `Iterable.iterator()` returns an *Iterator* object
- *Iterator* provides the method `.next` which returns a pair `(done, value)`. Alternatively, `.next` can throw an exception when called on an exhausted Iterator.

Examples:

```js
function RangeSeq(from, to) {
    this.iterator = function() {
        var i = from;
        return {
            next: function() { return [i >= to, i++] }
        }
    }
}

function ArraySeq(ary) {
    this.iterator = function() {
        var i = 0;
        return {
            next: function() { return [ i >= ary.length, ary[i++]] }
        }
    }
}

function logN(seq, n) {
    var it = seq.iterator();

    while (n--) {
        let [done, value] = it.next();
        if (done) break;
        console.log(value)
    }
}

logN(new RangeSeq(100, 100000000), 5);

console.log('--------------');

logN(new ArraySeq([11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]), 5);
```

That said, modern JS engines have this kind of stuff built-in, so the Range example can be written much simpler as

```js
function RangeSeq(from, to) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
        for (let i = from; i < to; i++)
            yield i;
        }
}

n = 0;
rs = new RangeSeq(100, 10000000);

for (let x of rs) {
    if (n++ >= 5) break;
    console.log(x)

}
```

Comment: The pattern "return {next: function(){...} }" is new to me. There was somewhat similar stuff in the book, with "get: function(){...}" and "set: function(){...}", but kinda briefly. That's probably why his solution is verbose - he has to rely only on the stuff he had introduced the readers to.